# Chrome net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADMINISTRATOR

Tags: google-chrome

I have an error in Chrome.

When I try to visit my own site, I get an error for a Facebook share button in my console, so, I don't see the button.

The error I get in console is:

> GET http://www.facebook.com/v2.4/plugins/share_button.php?app_id=&channel=http%…www.rallypodium.tk%2Fnieuws%2F40&layout=button_count&locale=nl_NL&sdk=joey net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADMINISTRATOR

How can I fix this issue? I get this on every site I go...

Comment: In which network connection do you see this error? Can you access facebook from same browser session? This may be network policy set by the authorities or Admins of network you're connected with.

Comment: I use my homenetwork and if I try to access the URL in my browser, I also get blocked, but when I remove the `www`, it does work, but goes to `https://www.facebook.com`... I only get the issue in chrome?

Comment: Not good at webcoding, but then it may be because facebook accepts only the secure traffic, https. Try changing your website code to use https instead of http.

Comment: The problem is (I think) it takes the URL-type of the current site and it can't be changed... (mine is http)... I guess it's google chrome that returns the error, because on firefox, internet explorer, opera, etc... I don't get that error.

Comment: If this is a school / corporate Chromebook, ask your administrator / IT. If it is Chrome browser, sign out of Chrome (if you are using a Google Apps user).